# Quick Texts and Macros on Posts / CaseComments

Tags: macros

**Use Case**: I'm trying to implement standard responses using Quick Text/Macros between internal teams for Cases to reduce time spent on manual writing. An example of this standard text would be, "We're forwarding this information received from the customer containing the following details -- "

**Questions**:

1. Can Quick Text be used on Post (Chatter) or Case Comments?
2. If not, can Macros be used for the same?

**Analysis**: From what I understand, Quick Text and Macros can only be used on limited Actions such as Email, Log a Call, Tasks, etc, and are generally used in conjunction. Has anyone ever implemented the scenario above OR using an alternate solution?

Answer (score 0):

OMG, I never actually checked before, and no, it looks like it can't be! This is ridiculous! The [Quick Text Help Docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=quick_text_insert.htm&type=5) specifically don't mention chatter, and there is no little Quick Text Icon in the Post window, where there is in the Email compose window in the Case Feed. Also the handy ctrl+. (that is hold down control whilst pressing the period or full stop key), does not activate anything in Post, where it does in Email.

And No, Macros won't help either. You can't choose the Post button or the Share an Update in the Macro editor.

The convoluted way to work around it, is to:

1. Create text field named Status Update
2. Created a Quick Action with just the Status Update on the Layout
3. Add a Related Record Component to the Case Page, and ensure it is ALWAYS VISIBLE (Macros only work on visible Quick Actions).
4. Create a Macro, selecting the Related Record Component, then the Status Update field.
5. Enter the Quick Text in the Status Update Field choosing Replace Existing Text
6. Create a Process Builder - on field change of Status Update and add a Chatter Post to the record with the contents of the Chatter Post and then clear the Status Update field. Bonus, add a StatusUpdate topic to the Post so you can quickly get to a feed of all Status Updates

(Note: You could just do Feed Tracking on Status Update field but it would a) not clear the field value, b) show the previous and current post, and c) not allow you to add a topic).

But the whole idea is HORRIBLE because you would have to create a Macro for each and every Quick Text, which defeats the purpose of Quick Text, which is meant to be user editable.

What a completely horrible and ludicrous situation. Oh, and of course there is [an idea for it](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000EC6uQAG). Note that the first post on the Idea says to copy the Quick Text and paste it into Chatter. Well again that defeats the purpose of Quick Text as you can't use Merge Fields.

Comment: I have a YouTube video about Macros from Spring '18. (excuse the bad sound), it is time to update it, but I might wait for the release notes, but not holding out hope. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kW5a7zSk1j8&

Comment: Thanks, Jodie. What's also unfortunate is that neither works on 'Case Comments' as well. So there's no real way of speeding up the communication of standard responses between internal teams. I did try the Process Builder route as well but found it to be not so useful as there's no 'agent control' over responses being editable prior to posting.

Comment: Thanks, it would be great if you can upvote my answer as being helpful :)

Comment: I did, but my reputation is too low for it to appear :)

Comment: Ah, thanks for trying anyway :)

Comment: I have noted, that the Release Notes for Winter '20 do nothing to solve any of these issues. Sorry.